# convert struct to struct in golang

Tags: go

trying to figure out what the best option is to convert one struct to another, Example

```
type user1 struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
    UserName string
}

type user2 struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName string
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest is probably to simply do something like `u2 := user2{FirstName: u1.FirstName, LastName: u1.LastName}`. That is assuming you don't mind that the username is lost in the "conversion".

It's possible to build more general converters using reflection, but I would normally try to structure my code so it's not needed.