# How to convert parent type to child type

Tags: go

Given the following types:

```
type (
    Parent struct {
        name string
        surname string
    }

    Child struct {
        *Parent
        sport String
    }
)

...

func (p *Parent) GetSport() string {
   return ((*Child)(p)).sport // does not work
}
```

How do I convert `*Parent` to `*Child`?

Comment: So you expect that after converting `sport` property will appear?

Comment: Yes, I know `Parent` is also a `Child` and I want to cast it.

Comment: Make sure you know how to use search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416188/convert-struct-to-struct-in-golang

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613271/golang-is-conversion-between-different-struct-types-possible

Comment: I know how to use search. What you suggest is not what I'm looking for. I need to conver a pointer of type `*Parent` to a pointer of type `*Child`.

Comment: You know __what__ is pointer, right?

Comment: @j3d Are you sure you want to convert `*Parent` to `*Child` and not the other way around? Because from my understanding (I'm not an expert in go), based on the struct definition, there is no way `Parent` can carry information about `sport`, how can you think that is supposed to work?

Comment: I see... got the point. See my own answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func (p *Parent) Convert() *Child {
   return &Child{p, ""}
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/saGvRu_rIk

The problem is there’s no data about `sport`. So we have to put empty line.